# How to find the username of a hostname in linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to know how I find the username of a hostname in linux 
eg 
***[username]*** @ [hostname] 
I wish to find the username. What command should I use?

thanks anyway

Comment: So you wish to find the Holy Grail of spammers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this question is better for [superuser](https://superuser.com/).  But in case you want to know how to do it for future use in a script, then the command you are looking for is:

```
$ whoami
```

That should work.

If you have changed users, and you want to know what user you used to log in, then use:

```
$ logname
```